# Concatenate variable to node value

Tags: 8, theming

```
{%
  set fields_array = [
    'field_address',
    'field_phone',
  ]
%}
{% for field in fields_array %}
  {{ node.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

How to concate dynamic value to node object?

Comment: You can concatenate like `'field_address_' ~ value`, but maybe you are wanting array keys like `{{ field.0.value}}`?

Comment: @Prestosaurus In that code, `field` is a string, so `field.0.value` would not give what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

To get a field with the field name stored in the variable `field` you can use the method `get()` on the node:

```
{{ node.get(field).value }}
```